# Do transcendental numbers contain any string of digits?

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers

It is often said that $\pi$ contains any string of digits. **But does the property "transcendental" imply "contains any string of digits?**

Comment: Related: math.stackexchange.com/questions/216343/does-pi-contain-all-possible-number-combinations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Consider the [Liouville number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number) $\sum_k{\frac{1}{10^{k!}}}$.  It is transcendental but all of its digits are $0$ or $1$.  As for $\pi$, it is unknown whether it contains any string of digits, but it is conjectured to have the stronger property of being [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number) in all bases.

Comment: Like is said here, you need to *prove* that such numbers are normal. If you want to prove some transcendental number of your choice is normal, it is indeed very very difficult. As far as I know, only the Champernowne constant has been proved to be normal so far (this one is just $.012345678910111213141516...$), but that's very nearly obvious compared to the others.

Comment: Being normal in all bases is an interesting property in that it is true of almost all numbers yet not a single example is known.

Comment: @marty, Chaitin's constant is normal in all bases.  But AFAIK no _computable_ examples are known.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1690285/does-there-exist-a-computable-number-that-is-normal-in-all-bases