# Does there exist a computable number that is normal in all bases?

Tags: number-theory

Following up on [this exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1689406/1284) with Marty Cohen...

Almost all numbers are normal in all bases (absolutely normal), but there are only a countable number of computable numbers, so it is plausible that none of them are absolutely normal.  Now I don't expect to be able to prove this since it would imply $\pi$, $\sqrt{2}$, etc. are not absolutely normal.  Also I don't expect to be able to find a particular computable number that is normal in all bases, since Marty states none are known.  But is it possible to show non-constructively that there is some computable number which is absolutely normal?

Comment: I think that by virtue of being computable it will have to be more or less a constructive proof.

Comment: Is yet answer, whether there is a computable number that is normal in infinitely many bases or normal in all but finitely many? In all seems to be a rather strong argument to start out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below are a couple of papers for what you want. For more, google [computable absolutely normal](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22computable+absolutely+normal+number%22).

Verónica Becher and Santiago Figueira, [*An example of a computable absolutely normal number*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397501001700), **Theoretical Computer Science** 270 #1-2 (6 January 2002), 947-958. [Another copy [here](http://www.glyc.dc.uba.ar/santiago/papers/absnor.pdf).]

Verónica Becher, Pablo Ariel Heiber, and Theodore A. Slaman, [*A computable absolutely normal Liouville number*](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2015-84-296/S0025-5718-2015-02964-0/), **Mathematics of Computation** 84 #296 (November 2015), 2939-2952.